# Java script values set into index of asp drop down

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have asp.net drop down list but I want to load previous classic asp page value into index of the drop down list using Java script.

I can able to take the previous page value with use of Java script.but I am unable set into asp drop down index when page is loaded. Drop down list showing only data from data base not from Java script value.

```
Protected void page_load()
{
    this.BindCountrydropdown();
}
Protected void BindCountrydropdown()
{
     /*I have written stored procedure to load values using Data adapter and data table*/
     this.ddlCountry.DataTextField=“Countryname”;
     this.ddlCountry.DataValueField=“CoubtryID”;
     this.ddlCountry.Databind();
}
```

In `.aspx` page. Java script:

```
<script>
    function loadpreviouspagevalues()
    {
        document.getElementById(“ddlCountry”).value=window.opener.parent.document.getElementById(“CountryName”).value;
    }
</script>
<body onload =“ loadpreviouspagevalues()”>
    <asp:DropDownList ID=“ddlCountry” runat =“server”> </asp:DropDownList>
   ...
```

Country name should loaded into ddlCountry index values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are multiple errors just in your javascript function.

```
function loadpreviouspagevalues(){
    document // should not be a capital "D"
    .getElementById //  No Extra "." should go after this
    ("ddlCountry").value = window.opener.parent.document.getElementById("CountryName").value; 
    // I am also skeptical about the inverted commas that you have used here. These are not surely correct
}
```

Change these and test. Also, when dealing with JavaScript, it is crucial to check browser console to see if any error is there and resolve it accordingly.

---

I see, you are fetching the value from another page, I would suggest you first validate if the value is properly being returned or not. If it is, then there is the syntactical issue that you need to fix in JavaScript.

Comment: I have edited and tested but it is not loading java script value, instead its loading values from DB and showing. it is not working.

Comment: Check the console window and post the errors you see there.

Comment: I fetched the value into one of the "Text box" in second page, it is displaying but unable to display the value into second page drop down list. It is not throwing any error.

Comment: You need to post more details regarding your page. If you are redirecting to the second page from first, you can set a value using query string params

Comment: You cannot access the first page controls from second page unless you open the second page from first page i.e with window.open.

Comment: You need to post your entire logic in order for us to see and direct you in correct path.